# Passing C++ array to function

Tags: c++

I cannot figure out how to pass the `sales[]` array to the `BubbleSort()` function. The error I'm getting is that sales was not declared in this scope, like it's an undeclared variable. That's the only issue I'm having with everything. If I don't call the function, the program works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void BubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
}

int main() {

    //Variables
    //String to hold user data file
    string fileName;
    //Double to hold calculated sales average
    double averageSales;
    // Double to hold total sales
    double totalSales;
    // Int to read array size
    int arraySize;
    // Double to hold highest sales value
    double highest = 0;
    // Double to hold lowest sales value
    double lowest;
    // Char to hold rerun choice, default value is no
    char rerun = 'n';

    //Do / While loop for rerun choice
    do {

        //Get File Name from User
        cout << "Input Filename to read:" << endl;
        cin >> fileName;
        cout << "File Name: " << fileName << endl;

        // Open files stream
        ifstream file;
        file.open(fileName.c_str());

        //Check File Steam
        if (file.is_open()) {
            // Read arraySize Variable from first line of file
            file >> arraySize;

            // Create array from arraySize variable; read from file
            double sales[arraySize];

            // Read data into array
            for (int i = 0; i<arraySize; i++) {
                file >> sales[i];
            }

            // Find Total Sales & Average
            for (int i = 0; i<arraySize; i++) {
                totalSales += sales[i];
            }
            averageSales = totalSales / arraySize;

            //Find largest Sales
            for (int i = 0; i<arraySize; i++) {
                if (sales[i] > highest) {
                    highest = sales[i];
                }
            }

            //Find lowest Sales - set default lowest value to the highest value
            lowest = highest;
            for (int i = 0; i<arraySize; i++) {
                if (sales[i] < lowest) {
                    lowest = sales[i];
                }
            }

            //Close File stream
            file.close();
        }
        else {
            cout << "Error Opening File" << endl;
        }

        //Sort Array
        BubbleSort(sales, arraySize);

        //Output Sales data
        cout << "Total Sales: " << totalSales << endl;
        cout << "Average Sales: " << averageSales << endl;
        cout << "Highest Sales amount: " << highest << endl;
        cout << "Lowest Sales Amount: " << lowest << endl;

        //Choice to rerun
        cout << endl << "Would you like to run again? Y/N " << endl;
        cin >> rerun;
    } while (rerun == 'y' || rerun == 'Y');
}
```

Comment: Inconsistent indentation will discourage users from reading your example.

Comment: Shouldnt this: BubbleArray(sales, arraySize); be this BubbleSort(sales, arraySize); ?

Comment: `double sales[arraySize];` is not portable c++. The size of an array must be a compile time constant. Some compilers allow it through extensions but it is not standard. Consider `std::vector<double> sales(arraySize);` instead.

Comment: `sales` is declared inside your `if (file.is_open())` block and is only valid inside it.  Also, `double sales[arraySize];` is not valid C++ when `arraySize` is not a constant expression, although some compilers accept it as an extension.  Use `std::vector` instead of an array.

Comment: Adding salt to the wound, fixing everything else, your inner loop `for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)` for your bubble sort will index out of bounds with `if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])` once `j` reaches `(n-1)` (the last iteration), leading to *undefined behavior* and much wailing and sobbing. Don't do that.

Comment: you need to read about [scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). The array is indeed not declared in the scope you are trying to use it.

Comment: It was the scope, thank you. I cannot mark comments as answers, though.

Comment: @JasonBrown, just as a tip, if you are using C++ study the STL. check std::vector it will help you A LOT;

Comment: I will definitely do that, as for the scope of this program, I cannot.

Comment: @Jason Brown then you should use dynamic array and new.. and if you say that you cannot.. then.. you 'll stay with predefined array size. 'double sales[arraySize];' line wouldn't compile or may create whole nest of issues with those rare compilers that support it as non-standard extension of language (in fact, they internally use std::vector or std::array pattern). That's not only portability and standard-compliance issue, that array isn't  trivial and POD, although it may decay to one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you declare variable `sales` inside an `if`-block, whereas you call `BubbleSort` outside of this `if`-block. Hence, the variable is out of scope and cannot be used for the call.

Further, note that `void BubbleSort(int arr[], int n)` expects an integer array, while `sales` is an array of doubles, i.e. `double sales[arraySize]`.

Calling `BubbleSort(sales, arraySize)` should yield a compiler error once you have corrected the scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your array inside 'if' block. It exists only there. Moreover, 'sales' is array of doubles, but your function expects an array of integers.